# stream_get_line How to set where it starting to read the file?

Tags: php, curl

this is a simple question but i watched the php doc and i didn't found anything so i'm asking you if you got any idea / way to reach my goal.

I'm reading a file and trying to get it to start writing at a specifique word.

(The file i get is coming from an Curl command:

`curl -F 'file@logbackup-infitarif' https://mylink`
My php:

```
<?php
    // print_r($_FILES); 
    print_r($_FILES["file"]); 
    $file = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    print_r($file);

    var_dump(get_resource_type($file));

   
    
    print(stream_get_line($file, $lengh, $ending = "speedup"));
?>
```

Actually with this code, it's reading all the file from the start -> "speedup". But i want it to start at the word "to the word / sentence "total size is" .

The text in the file it's reading:

```
logbackup-final.txt                                                                                 
logbackup-final.txt                                                                                 0000777 0002002 0000144 00000000331 14303633743 013533  0                                                                                                    ustar   stag                            users                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2022-08-30
receiving incremental file list
2022/08/30 16:09:56|test/
2022/08/30 16:09:56|test/DiskStation214_20220622.dss
sent 47 bytes  received 11,370 bytes  7,611.33 bytes/sec
total size is 15,402  speedup is 1.35
```

Any idea or way to do that's? Thanks if so! :)

Comment: I think you are trying to make your life too complicated. Just read the file line by line and test the start of the live for `total size` you only have a few lines so speed is not a problem

Comment: Use [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and a simple IF test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is to complex, just do a simple read of the file, line by line and check each line for the info you are searching for

```
$find_str = 'total size is';
$keep_for_later = '';

$fp = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r");

if ($fp) {
    while (($line = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== false) {
        if ( strpos($line, $find_str) !== false ) {
            $keep_for_later = $line;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
echo $keep_for_later;
```